# UIView size and storyboards

Tags: ios, uiview, xcode-storyboard

I have a custom UIView in a storyboard using autolayout, so I don't know the exact height of the UIView.   I need it to draw individual items in the view, so larger UIViews will have more rows.

Where can I determine the height?   I want to initialize a data structure based on this, but so far the only place I've gotten a non-zero UIView height/width is in drawRect, and I'd like to set this up before I hit that method.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the size of the views frame from within viewDidAppear:
At this point, the view should have it's final dimensions calculated and you should be able to do what you want.

When you say more rows, what do you mean? Are you simply using a table view in your view?

Comment: I mean more rows of text that I'm placing in the view myself in the drawRect routine of the View

Answer (score 0):

`viewDidLayoutSubviews` in your view controller would be a sensible place to put this, though basing a data structure on the size of a view doesn't sound very MVC, but I'll assume you know what you're doing.

This will get called after rotation as well.

Comment: Yes, I would agree.  The data structure is basically a representation of what will fit in the view.  So if the view is tall, there will be more rows of text, vs a shorter view that will have fewer rows.  If there's a better way to get that info so I can set this up, I'd like to use it, but so far I'm not seeing anywhere else.